# uploaded file contents being echoed out but not showing accent marks

Tags: php, utf

```
INT. PALO TORCIDO HIGH SCHOOL, CAFETER�A - DAY
```

Hi, I uploaded a .txt to my server and got the contents with fopen/fread and alsot used file_get_contents just in case.

I can't seem to figure out how to encode the special characters...

In my HTML i have my UTF set to 8. I also tried a PHP HEADER to use UTF-8 encoding.

what is the proper way to handle files with letters not part of the english alphabet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try utf8_encode()

```
echo utf8_encode(file_get_contents('file.txt'));
```

This works if the *.txt is encoded in Latin1.  If other encoding may be used too, detect the encoding using mb_detect_encoding() and encode it to UTF8 with mb_convert_encoding()

Comment: hehe, i had utf8_decode() no wonder it wasn't working right... what is this btw -> '' I get that, everything else was encoded correctly... Inside the '' is suppose to be a little square